# How does one solve a trig equation containing a linear term

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Whilst trying to work out a minimisation problem, I came to the inequality

$$\frac{\pi}{2n} - \frac{x}{n} < \cos{x}$$

I know how you could solve it if the $x$ on the left side were also inside a trig function, but I don't know how to solve it like this.
Is it possible?

I want to solve it for $x$ lying in the interval [0, $\frac{\pi}{2}$].
(0° to 90°)

Comment: What conditions do you have on $n$ or $x$?

Comment: It might help to notice that the two sides are equal when $x=\pi/2$.

Comment: x is a number in the interval [0, Pi/2], n can basically be any positive real number

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks, but I'm interested in solutions in the interval of 0 to pi/2. Sorry that wasn't clear

Comment: In WolframAlpha it exceeded the standard computation time, but when I used some positive number for n it could solve it. And there I noticed that for values smaller than 2 (or 1.5 or smth like that) there is a solution interval that's at least partly contained in the 0 to Pi/2 interval. So I wondered how to solve that generally

Comment: It still might help to notice that the two sides are equal when $x=\pi/2$. You may be able to use that fact, together with estimates on derivatives, to draw conclusions about ranges where one side exceeds the other.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Okay, I'll give that a try. But is there really no way to solve it completely analytically?

Comment: For values of $n$ for which there is no obvious solution to ${\pi\over2n}-{x\over n}=\cos x$, there will be no analytic way to solve that equation, nor to solve the inequality. It may be possible to solve it using the *Lambert W-function*, and some people consider that to be an analytic solution, some don't. There are always numerical methods.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh, okay. Thanks! Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done, answer posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For values of $n$ for which there is no obvious solution to ${\pi\over2n}-{x\over n}=\cos x$ there will be no analytic way to solve that equation, nor to solve the inequality. It may be possible to solve it using the *Lambert W-function*, and some people consider that to be an analytic solution, some don't. There are always numerical methods.

Comment: The equation isn't solvable in terms of Lambert W.